# How fade in a button in android

Tags: java, android

I have a layout activity with 4 buttons. the button should fade in after the activity is started. how to fade in  4 buttons when the activity is started. i am clear in xml part but i facing problem in java side

Comment: Please, show us your error to try help you

Comment: I have not written java code

Comment: In fact you want all the buttons to fade when you push one of the buttons ?

Comment: No no ..once a activity is started ... 4 buttons should display in fade in manner

Answer (score 6):

Very simple:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<View> viewsToFadeIn = new ArrayList<View>();

    viewsToFadeIn.add(findViewById(R.id.b1));
    viewsToFadeIn.add(findViewById(R.id.b2));
    viewsToFadeIn.add(findViewById(R.id.b3));
    viewsToFadeIn.add(findViewById(R.id.b4));

    for (View v : viewsToFadeIn)
    {
        v.setAlpha(0); // make invisible to start
    }

    for (View v : viewsToFadeIn)
    {
        // 3 second fade in time
        v.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(3000).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a third-party library to do it. You can use this one:

```
**compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'**
```

Now you can write something like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idButon);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "alpha", 1f).setDuration(100).start();
```

Comment: You don't need a 3rd party library to do that.  View class has a built in animation operation.

Comment: It still works, this answer's still correct.

Comment: That's a waste. Let's not import external libraries for the sake of importing them. It's gonna cause you more harm than good in the long term.